# Indexing and searching of pdf content

Tags: iphone, search, pdf, indexing

I have been searching for Iphone programming ways to search and index downloaded pdf documents.The app that I want to make will have facility to download pdf files on the device and store it as various pdf files in a directory, the user can use the search function and should be able to search for the keyword in all the files.It is similar to grep functionality in MAC.
 My problem is searching in all the files quickly since I am not able to figure out what is the best way to do the indexing so that search is fast.

please suggest.

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 0):

I can't help but think that the best solution would be to dump the text of the pdf (that will be later searched) into a sql backed database when the pdf is downloaded and access the database via core-data.